# Parallel.For vs Regular for loop with logical statements

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm trying to replicate the following in my `Parallel.For` loop:

```
   for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
       // do something here...      
   }
```

Please notice how I declare the `i` counter:

```
i <= totalPages
```

I would like to replicate this with the `Parallel.For` loop or using PLINQ...

```
 Parallel.For(1, totalPages, i => {

 });
```

But there's no way I can tell the parallel for loop to include the last number.

Say if totalPages is = 15, I'd like that number to be included as well in the counter....

Can this be done via `Parallel.For` loop or PLINQ?

P.S. guys, `totalPages` is just a plain integer number, not a collection.

Comment: it should loop through all the items in `totalPages` collection. Why do you think it won't  ?

Comment: @Shyju totalPages isn't the collection, but a plain integer number..

Comment: Anyone guys ? It can't be that they haven't thought of this ... ?

Comment: Just use totalPages + 1 in the Parallel.For

Comment: Should I use 1 to totalPages + 1 or 0 to TotalPages +1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload you are using for `Parallel.For` is using the below parameters

1. fromInclusive
2. toExclusive

As the parameter name implies, the from is including the current number in the loop. So if you pass 1 as the value, The loop will include 1 as well. But for the second parameter, It is exclusive. It does not include the "to" number. So if you pass 5, It will not include 5 in the iterations of the loop.

You can add `1` to the totalPages variable value and pass the result of that arithmetic operation as `toExclusive` param value (Assuming totalPages  is of type `Int32` and `totalPages < Int32.MaxValue-1` (*To prevent arithmetic overflow exception*))

```
Parallel.For(1, totalPages+1, i =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
});
```

This will run for 1,2,3,4,5 for i (**not necessarily in the same order** though)

Answer (score 0):

You can add one into limit variable as below

```
Parallel.For(seed, limit+1,i=>{ //statements })
```